# windows 11 22H2 fails to install due to being unable to check compatibility

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I'm trying to get my PC up to date with the windows 11 22H2 update - I'm currently running 21H2 / OS Build 22000.978. I've tried updating all 3 ways - windows updater, using the set up tool and the ISO mounted directly and I seem to be having it fail by telling me windows is unable to check if my hardware is compatible.

*Amusingly* the windows 11 setup tool says I'm compatible

[image]

as does the health check tool

I'm running a 9th generation intel processor (a core i9 9900k), and a modern GPU (a 3000 series nvidia)  and was able to upgrade to windows 11 with no issues. I meet or exceed all the requirements for running the OS.  Normally [setupdiags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) lets me know what's the issue but it I can't find this specific error.

Just to be safe, I've checked my system with `sfc /scannow`, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` and the system seems fine.

I've tried clearing out the C:$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ (via the cleanup tool) and software sources

`0x80888002` is the specific error code I get, but you can find the setupdiags output below

```
Matching Profile found: FindAbruptDownlevelFailure - 55882B1A-DA3E-408A-9076-23B22A0472BD
SetupDiag version: 1.6.2107.27002
System Information:
    Machine Name = AURORA
    Manufacturer = System manufacturer
    Model = System Product Name
    HostOSArchitecture = 2057
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 20190129000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = 0805
    BiosVersion = 0805
    HostOSVersion = 
    HostOSBuildString = 22000.1.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.22621.1 (ni_release.220506-1250)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Professional
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = 
    UpgradeStartTime = 30/9/2022 11:33:44 pm
    UpgradeEndTime = 30/9/2022 11:35:11 pm
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 00:01:27
    CV = lkuw80lu+E+qknub
    ReportId = ace42ba7-4208-4be3-a401-036ec5e62dd1


Error: SetupDiag reports abrupt down-level failure.
Last Operation: Finalize
Error: 0x80888002 - 0x40008
LogEntry: 2022-09-30 23:34:59, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::InitializeData (1640):   Failed to extract data file resource: [0x80888002].[gle=0x80888002]

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.
```

From the comments I looked at `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\diagerr` and

```
 <z:row Cls="D" Sev="33554432" Maj="Def" Min="Def" LN="675" Fil="" Fun="Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::ExtractResourceToFile" Uid="34226176" Msg="Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::ExtractResourceToFile (675): Could not LoadLibrary to resource: [2]." PID="3840" TID="22452" Con="" Exe="C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SetupHost.exe" Mod="" Err="-2147024894" MD="" DT="2022-10-01T20:51:02"/>
<z:row Cls="D" Sev="33554432" Maj="Def" Min="Def" LN="4721" Fil="" Fun="Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::GetAlternateData" Uid="34226176" Msg="Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::GetAlternateData (4721): Failed to extract data file resource: [0x80070002]." PID="3840" TID="22452" Con="" Exe="C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SetupHost.exe" Mod="" Err="-2147024894" MD="" DT="2022-10-01T20:51:02"/>
<z:row Cls="D" Sev="33554432" Maj="Def" Min="Def" LN="2115" Fil="" Fun="Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::InitializeRunOptions" Uid="34226176" Msg="Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::InitializeRunOptions (2115): Error checking for latest SDB, swallowing: [0x80070002]." PID="3840" TID="22452" Con="" Exe="C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SetupHost.exe" Mod="" Err="-2147024894" MD="" DT="2022-10-01T20:51:02"/>
<z:row Cls="D" Sev="33554432" Maj="Def" Min="Def" LN="1017" Fil="" Fun="" Uid="34226176" Msg="Appraiser: ERROR,SdbpGetManifestedMergeStubAlloc,1017,SdbpGetMergeSdbsDisabled failed [c0000034]
" PID="3840" TID="22452" Con="" Exe="C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SetupHost.exe" Mod="" Err="0" MD="" DT="2022-10-01T20:51:02"/>
```

looks relevant

Since the hardware is *entirely* windows 11 compatible as per the PC health check, I'm not sure why the installer can't seem to check. Is there any way to fix this short of a full reinstall?

[Neowin](https://www.neowin.net/news/windows-11-22h2-apparently-causing-problems-on-nvidia-graphics-cards/) suggested the GPU driver might be the cause, and updating the nvidia driver to 518.48 would help. Updated and rebooted and still having the same issues

Comment: maybe related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/unable-to-install-windows-11-22h2-error-0x80888002/73ac19ab-e450-41f5-9a8e-39408a9b5c18

Comment: That appears to be a Windows Insider error  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/unable-to-install-windows-11-22h2-error-0x80888002/73ac19ab-e450-41f5-9a8e-39408a9b5c18    .... No issues here with Windows 11 Production.

Comment: Have you run the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-troubleshooter-19bc41ca-ad72-ae67-af3c-89ce169755dd)?

Comment: [How do I Solve Error Code 0x80888002 in Windows 11](https://www.howtoedge.com/solve-error-code-0x80888002/)

Comment: @John Running production for sure

Comment: Microsoft might have hardened the hardware requirements. But perhaps you could try installing first 21H2. See [How to download Windows 11 21H2 ISO after 22H2 releases](https://pureinfotech.com/download-windows-11-21h2-iso-after-22h2/).

Comment: @harrymc this system is up to date *and* the hardware requirements are met in every way

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Not sure : 20H2 is Windows 10 and not Windows 11.

Comment: .... that's on me. Body says 22H2 as does the supporting information - I definately am running windows 11 and ought to have added the specific version

Comment: @DavidPostill https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZO5T.png this is what the troubleshooter found. I'll try rebooting shortly and trying to update again - no luck after that

Comment: There is a known compatibility blocker that will prevent the upgrade to Windows 11 22H2. Do you have a printer installed? While unlikely given the issues the troubleshooter is pointing out might be worth investigating if your printer installation is applicable to the blocker

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Your inability to upgrade most definitely is linked to the Microsoft IPP Class Driver compatibility blocker.

Comment: ... I shall be quite cross if its that. I *do* have an older printer (an epson l365) - any pointers on what to look at?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - [You](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-22H2#2913msgdesc) can uninstall it, perform the upgrade, then reinstall it once the issue has been fixed

Comment: Maybe try a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Media Creation link. Does all Windows updates and most driver updates. Worth considering.

Comment: “The upgrade blocker is set by the Microsoft IPP Class Driver printer driver. This must have been set in the night of September 23, 2022. Before that the user had error 0x80070002 in the Safe OS phase.” - My source continues to indicate that a XML file contained within *C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther* within one of the Property nodes will specify the upgrade to be blocked. *Stupid Google showed my results for an entirely different error code* the XML file might still hold some answers though

Comment: Can confirm its not the printer, uninstalled

Comment: this is a fairly 'clean' system so nothing particularly exotic here. Monitors, mouse, keyboard, and have all the 'interesting' hardware removed. I've run (and documented) running sfc /scannow and dism commands. Updates are mostly up to date except this one

Comment: Okay, I just didn't see restore health parameter, maybe the answer on the registry hack will work though. Good luck with it!

Comment: Have you tried to [Reset Windows Update](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-windows-update-in-windows-11.3808/)? If all else fails, you might try a clean install of 22H2.

Comment: The reset didn't help. A clean install isn't a fix :D, and needs me to do some prep work, like backups

Comment: Just so I can find it later, and to 'better' future posts - https://www.neowin.net/news/windows-11-22h2-apparently-causing-problems-on-nvidia-graphics-cards/ it *might* be the video card. Updated it and am trying again

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. :/

Comment: Not yet I am afraid. Pondering a reinstall. It might be worth going through some of my failed fixes and see if they work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'd run [the AveYo media creation tool](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat) to generate an installer for another PC while trouble shooting this PC, and it had turned off the TPM check on the PC I was running it on for some reason. It has been a while so I don't recall *if* I had done something wrong, or what the root cause of this happening could have been other than that.

You can check this by running `wmic /namespace:"\\root\subscription" path __EventFilter where Name="Skip TPM Check on Dynamic Update" get` in an elevated command shell (NOT powershell). If you get something like this

[image]

You should run `wmic /namespace:"\\root\subscription" path __EventFilter where Name="Skip TPM Check on Dynamic Update" delete`

Then check again and you should get get "no instances available"

Naturally this will work *only* if you had a valid TPM and accidentally turned off TPM checks as I had.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but you can try the Windows 10 [registry hack](https://www.howtogeek.com/759925/how-to-install-windows-11-on-an-unsupported-pc/) to upgrade to 11.  This disables the compatibilty check.  It might work in your situation.

Comment: Maybe worth a shot, although someone having [a similar issue did not have it resolved by changing the reg key](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/unable-to-install-windows-11-22h2-error-0x80888002/73ac19ab-e450-41f5-9a8e-39408a9b5c18?page=2) (latest reply at time of writing)

Comment: I tried it and... it was already set to 1, which has me confused, since this is a machine that's *always* been compatible, has TPM 2.0 and never used a modified installer

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well, it was worth a shot.  Ive never seen this happen before, so not sure what else it could be